# Should one keep on praying if they haven't realized that their prayers have been answered? Are prayers answered in dreams?

Tags: dua, dream

Allah listens to every prayer and answers all of them when the time's right.

Suppose one doesn't realize that He has answered or that an answer was from Him.

Question:

- Should one keep on praying in order for Allah to answer the prayers again and again?
- Does Allah also provide His answers in the dream? If so, how do you know it's from Allah?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to you first question is simple, be organized, precise and exact.

It is crucial to remember, you can achieve the same goal unlimited number of ways, when you ask Allah (swt) for something, do you know how many ways that something can be achieved? When you ask for a million dollars, how many ways can that goal be achieved? In how many different time frames?

The secret to success in this life is simple, knowledge. Knowledge of what you want, and knowledge of the paths that can take you to what you want. If you are not specific, then Allah (swt) will choose for you a path, and then you change your mind, then you get confused, and in the end you fail to achieve your goal.

One of the best prayers:

> "Allahumma Rabbana Atina fid-dunya hasanatan wafil- Akhirati hasanatan waqina athaban nar."
>
> "Oh Allah, our Lord, give us all the good of this world, and the good of the life hereafter, and save us from the punishment of the hell-fire."

In this prayer you leave it with Allah (swt), put your trust in Allah (swt) and let thy decide the best path for you, a path that will give you best in this life and in Akhira.

Some people ask for specific things in this life, destroying their prospects in Akhira (knowingly or not knowingly), there are many verses in Quran about those people, so please don't be one of those people.

Answer (score 0):

Praying is not only to get what you asked for or to be granted from allah by giving you of your needs. prying is the I'imad Deen , it's a Faridha. So if you asked something and didn't get it means Allah have heard you and he knows best then you, you may get it many years later for purpose as it's good for you. And if you want ask him to some decision or something you want do so it called Istikhara.

Sometimes we see the answer in dream when we do Istikhara as I met also the answer via dream. the right dream must be before sunrise (Fajr).

Comment: It's not true that we see the answer of Istikhara in dream! Please add you references.

Comment: where did you get that you would see your answer in a dream ???

Comment: yes sometimes can come in dream yes , but doesnt mean always , sooooometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Allah, listens to every pray, and gives a **positive** response to every prayer. Now you might want to ask, what about those prayers which were responded negatively, for example:

I prayed to stand first in my class. But I was second, Allah never responded **positively** to my prayers.

No that's wrong. Someone else from your class was also praying to get first position, and he was hardworking and was praying by heart. So Allah gave more positive response to his Pray.

Now, when you're getting an answer to your prayer, you see it! You see the things going well in your life. There might be a delay, but there can never be negativity in the response.

And as far as dreams are concerned, Allah Almighty knows what the dream is about. There is nothing hidden by Allah not even our dreams that not even we know what they were. Allah gives us responses to our questions in our Dreams, many people have seen true dreams.

I am not a man of God, but sometimes when I pray by heart, I get the answer in my dream and I can see what will happen in near future and it does happen.

To know whether it is from Allah or not, you can get this idea by these points:

1. You get this sort of dream when you're almost about to wake up, since a dream that you were having in the mid of the sleep is never memorable by you and you forget it. The dream that you have a while ago waking up, is in your mind and you can filter the answer from it.
2. You would never get an nightmare if it is from Allah, you will see everything as real as it would be in a real time.
3. You will never get superstitious effects in your dream. You will see real people, and you will see real things going on.

I sometimes get to see my family members in my dream who tell me things that they are about to tell me in the next day!

Comment: I've been 2 many countries in the M.E. & my wish is 2 go to KSA too mainly 2 convert to Islam. Everything/ everyone belong 2 Allah. However there are sacred places what He has chosen 2 worship Him. It s not a lame excuse, but what I have promised 2 Allah I will try 2 stick to it. Allah will show me the way. It s all up 2 Him 2 determine the day  the doors 2 enter KSA are widely open in order me 2 say the Shahada. Too many promises made 2 Allah have been broken in our lives. Can A man at least keep up 2 his promise to Allah when it comes 2 one of the most important things in a humans life?

Answer (score 0):

Not having an answer for a pray might be an answer itself. An answer that a person might be praying for a wrong thing.

A person might not know what is good or bad for him.

Allah may know that something he is praying for would turn out as bad experience or disaster, that he don't wish to this particular person.

On the other hand, one can be consistent in praying but not consistent in following steps that would lead to something he is praying for. Things don't happen for no reason. Being patient in moving step by step to a target and praying meanwhile, taking a pause and thinking if this is really one need might be a good strategy in getting a respond to the prayers.

Comment: My desire is as a non Muslim go to Saudi Arabia to say in Riyad the Shahada. I said to Allah that I will surely become a muslim if I can get a visa and visit S. A. I have tried to obtain a visa 2 times but without success. Does this mean Allah doesn t want me to become a muslim.

Comment: @Yahya777 you can become a muslim without leaving your house.